# Export all Redis data in json OR txt file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am using,

```
exec('redis-dump 127.0.0.1:6379 > db_full.json');
```

but it only create **'0 kb' file**. I am using it in my **Home Controller Constructor**.

How can I do this successful export? My **Framework** is **Laravel.**

Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

**Note: You guys are free to ask questions.**

Comment: Does your data is in the 1 database?

Comment: Yes it is in 1 database,  'default' => array(
   'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
   'port'     => 6379,
   'database' => 0,
  ),

Comment: You could use the [Log Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#logging) to print directly to your log in `storage/logs`